# grunt serve on vagrant box not showing

Tags: gruntjs, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

Running "grunt serve" on a VM shows no errors and according to command line dialogue appears to be serving as expected on 0.0.0.0:9000/#/ except that no browser (chrome) page is ever opened, and navigating to that address shows a 'Could not connect to 0.0.0.0:9000" error page.

Days of searching for a fix have been fruitless, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am running an Ubuntu Precise32 box with Vagrant and provisioning via Puppet to support development using Laravel 4 + AngularJS. Installed packages include:

php
apache
composer
mysql
phpmyadmin
ruby
nodejs
sass
compass
yeoman
generator-angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you configured forwarding port 9000 in Vagrantfile?

`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9000, host: 9000
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 35729, host: 35729`

The first one is for `grunt serve` and the second forwarding is for live-reload in Grunt.

Comment: @NolanLawrence After you did this, did `grunt serve` in your VM open a Chrome page for you? Were you able to connect to localhost:9000? All I've got now is a No Data Received error in Chrome on port 9000. I do get a "welcome" response on 35729 though.

Comment: @hiwaylon: Same here. Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error as hiwaylon commented on accepted answer. What solved for me was running:

```
 sed -i 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/' Gruntfile.js
```

before "grunt serve"

Comment: Your solution worked for me could you explain what the command did that make grunt serve working.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam It just replaces occurrence of `localhost` with `0.0.0.0` in your `Gruntfile.js`